# The bgsave on a redis server on windows always return failed, what to do?

Tags: redis

Today I took a look and found one of our redis server has a very serious problem. It can't save.

info

```
# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:82904
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:1
rdb_last_save_time:1444978843
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:1444978844
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:1448356070
```

Basically the last bgsave happened on Oct 11th, I can't restart it because I think I'll lose all the in memory data.

What should I do?

Comment: What kind of persistenc model is used by the redis server? Do you use AOF or only snapshotting?

Comment: I only see a dump.rdb file, and the last updated date is Oct 11th.

Comment: If the server currently is not in a productive environment you can try the SAVE command. But take care it will stop serving clients until the snapshot would be finished. Have a look into the [documentation](http://redis.io/commands/save)

Comment: Also not successful, it says the bgsave is in progrss

Comment: What does the logfile says?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ends up wrote an little app that read all the keys, dump them and so I can restore them. Now I've restarted my server, and restored everything.